# Passing URL variables to the security spring form

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authentication

I have an app, that should prefill login form with variables grabbed from URL.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/fornecedor/lista").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/fornecedor/cadastrarFornecedor").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/fornecedor/cadastrarFornecedor").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

I'm getting localhost:8080/login and of course form is empty So, I need to be able to get user from his identifier passed with such URL: localhost:8080/login?user=nome&password=12345 and pass this user to my custom login form:

But at the moment I can't get it - how can I get this path variable in code, and where can I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a controller for the login page that reads the URL parameters and provides that data to the view.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private static final String REQUEST_URL = "/login";
    private static final String VIEW = "login";

    @RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_URL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupLogin(@RequestParam("user") String user, @RequestParam("password") String password, HttpServletRequest request) {

        // adapt 'j_username' and 'j_password' depending on the names used in your login page
        request.setAttribute("j_username", user);
        request.setAttribute("j_password", password);

        return VIEW;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have never used spring, have any examples?

Comment: @Hugg See edited answer: added controller sample code